# Grant Extended Permissions within iFrame application tab

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to grant extended permissions while keeping a user 'on' a fan page application tab using the php sdk.

When I try this hoping to have the dialogue appear within the iFrame, a redirection is given to a a facebook logo which then asks for authorisation in the "_top" window - same as if I'd set this on the link element.

If granting permissions this way I'm then redirected to the web page, when I want to go back to the tab; using the tab URL for a redirect doesn't seem to be possible.

Is there a way around this? The intended action will be posting a link on a users wall once they've given permission.

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to post exactly? you may not need to allow anything of you are okay with the user posting these data using the [feed dialog](http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed)

Answer (score 0):

call the authorize dialog by setting the "_top" window.  Once the user authorizes your app and you are certain that you do indeed have an authorized user, use

```
header("Location: http://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=app_APPID");
```

This should allow them to authorize and then on success be redirected to the tab on your page.